# Weak topology generated equal to the original topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If we have ($\mathbb{R}$, standard topology), I was wondering what are the conditions that are given to the family of functions will result in us having a topology equal to it's original self.

I was guessing it is:

1. set of all functions continuous with respect to the usual topology.

Since the inverse of any open set will be open and they form a basis of the original topology. Hence the topology generated will be the same as the original.

2. The set of identity function on $\mathbb{R}$ itself

   since the preimage of any open set is same open set itself and thus the sub basis form by these are the same as the original basis.

Are my two guesses correct? What is the exact condition we need to impose also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment in lack of reputation.  But I'd suggest reading [Wikipedia Initial Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).  That gives few ideas.  To summarize: it's enough to generate enough open sets to form subbasis, but that's just reversing the definition.

And yeah, as subbasic sets are open in normal topology, so both families form subbasis for normal topology via inverse images.  It's enough to check would-be identity for subbase $B$, and $id^{-1}(S)=S$ for all $S \in B$.  And by being subbase, it's again subbase for the "new topology".

Comment: Thanks! but in the second case, will the weak topology generated by the set of all continuous functions be weaker than the original topology, or are they actually the same topology generated?

Comment: I tried to clarify, my answer: I forgotten word subbase.  By taking any subbase, and transporting it to subbase by id, you get same topology by initial selection of subbase.   As for the comparing subbases to find out which generates stronger topology, I can't give much advice, but to inspect the generated basis.  Adding more functions adds more subbasic open sets, but those should be compatible because of the topology of the codomain is the same.

Comment: Just an idea that might be relevant or not.  You usually get way more subbasic open sets this way than you actually need.  The subbases are not unique, and open set topology is a subbase for itself, showing how big it can get.  There is usually no unique minimum subbase to generate some particular topology.